# MaskRCNN TensorFlow Lite Inference Issue. No output from TFLite Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution ( Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1034-azure x86_64)):
- TensorFlow installed from (source- Pip Install):
- TensorFlow version (2.3.0):

**Command used to run the converter**

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_model)
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]

converter.optimizations = [ tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT ]

tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

**link to Jupyter notebook and tflite model**

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pTB33fTSo5ENzevobTvuG7hN4YmiCPF_?usp=sharing

**Commands used for inference**

```
### Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model_2.3.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

### Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

### Test the model on random input data.
input_data_1 = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_details[0]['shape']), dtype=np.float32)
input_data_2 = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_details[1]['shape']), dtype=np.float32)
input_data_3 = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_details[2]['shape']), dtype=np.float32)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data_1)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]['index'], input_data_2)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[2]['index'], input_data_3)

interpreter.invoke() ---> Kernel is getting stuck here. No output. I am executing the code from jupyter.
```

**The output from the converter invocation**

No output in Jupyter.

Segmentation fault (core dumped) -- When executed in command line.

**Failure details**

Conversion is successful. But there is no output from model.

Could you guys please provide some ideas? I am stuck here and don't know how to proceed!

Comment: Is it possible to try convert/inference with TF2.4? I do not like those `CropAndResize`: they are marked as "flex" but should be from `tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS`. [TensorFlow Lite with select TensorFlow ops are available in the TensorFlow pip package version since 2.3 for Linux and 2.4 for other environments.](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#python) but just in case lets try from updating TF version and without custom ops: `converter.experimental_new_converter = False`

Comment: Hi Alex, I raised the same with tensorflow team and they suggested to run it with nightly and it worked. Thank you